# How do I render a pdf in the browser generated from DynamicPDF Cloud API?

Tags: c#, pdf, blazor

Using DynamicPDF's Cloud API, instead of generating a pdf back to the local file system, I would like it to directly open in another browser tab to be available for printing immediately. How do I accomplish that?

The method I am using (.NET Core 6 / Blazor) is below:

```
public async Task CallDynPDFCloudAPI()
    {
  var basePath = @"JSONFiles\";
  var apiKey = "foo";
  var cloudPath = "bar.dlex";
  Pdf pdf = new Pdf();
  pdf.ApiKey = apiKey;
  LayoutDataResource layoutDataResource = new LayoutDataResource(basePath + "FooBar.json");
  pdf.AddDlex(cloudPath, layoutDataResource);
  PdfResponse pdfResponse = pdf.Process();
  if (pdfResponse.IsSuccessful)
  {
    File.WriteAllBytes(basePath + "Manifest_" + manifestBranch + ".pdf", pdfResponse.Content);
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine(pdfResponse.ErrorJson);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reread article on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0

```
@page "/file-download-1"
@using System.IO
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<h1> File Download Example</h1>

<button @onclick = "DownloadFileFromStream" >
    Download File From Stream
</button>

@code {

    private Stream CallDynPDFCloudAPI()
    {
        var basePath = @"JSONFiles\";
        var apiKey = "foo";
        var cloudPath = "bar.dlex";
        Pdf pdf = new Pdf();
        pdf.ApiKey = apiKey;
        LayoutDataResource layoutDataResource = new LayoutDataResource(basePath + "FooBar.json");
        pdf.AddDlex(cloudPath, layoutDataResource);
        PdfResponse pdfResponse = pdf.Process();
        if (pdfResponse.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return new MemoryStream(pdfResponse.Content);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("");
        }
    }


    private async Task DownloadFileFromStream()
    {
        var fileStream = CallDynPDFCloudAPI();
        var fileName = "file.pdf";

        using var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: fileStream);

        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", fileName, streamRef);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to access the PDF content for this request from another browser tab. I'd recommend opening the new tab before making the call and then streaming it there. If you're using an 'a href' link, you can accomplish this by setting the 'target="_blank"' property of the 'a href'. If this is a form submission, you can set the 'target="_blank"' property of the 'form'.

The other option would be to store the PDF somewhere temporarily (as a file, in a DB or in BLOB storage) then stream it to the other tab once it's opened.

Answer (score 0):

Ive impletented @Mihal's answer, with modified code suggested by @DynamicPDF to achieve the result I was looking for. My two goals were:

1. Not clutter the client device with excessive dowloaded files
2. Not needing to save the file in Server or DB

Javascript:

```
   <script>
        window.downloadFileFromStream = async (fileName, 
            contentStreamReference) => {
            const arrayBuffer = await contentStreamReference.arrayBuffer();
            const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

//--Opens PDF file in new Tab
            fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.blob())
                .then(data => window.open(URL.createObjectURL(data), '_blank'))

//--Downloads file to Browser (uncomment if desired)
            //const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
            //anchorElement.href = url;
            //anchorElement.download = fileName ?? 'Manifest';
            //anchorElement.click();
            //anchorElement.remove();
            //URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
    </script>
```

*NOTE! My application is purely internal-facing to our organization. Our Windows client machines and browsers are managed by Group Policy. I have not yet tested this on Mac / Safari clients yet.